# Getting all filters in kendo angular grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

How would I get a list of all the filters being used in a kendo angular grid?
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/

I have access to the grid in my angular component like so

```
@ViewChild(GridComponent) private grid;
```

I set the remote data

```
this.dataService.getItems().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.grid.data = data;
    }
)
```

I have to call an API similar to this. I tried using the [filterChange](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-filterchange) event - it works fine until I clear a filter, the event fires but doesn't tell which event is fired.

```
.../api/items?filter1=value&filter2=value
```

Comment: The `filterChange` event will always return the currently active filter(s). If you clear a filter, it is removed. (the event may even be empty if that was the only active one)

Comment: @Philipp you're right, I missed a line and this was causing the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the below line and this was causing unexpected behavior. Instead of containing information about all the filters it was only showing information about the filter that was changed.

```
<kendo-grid
        ....
        [filter]="filter"
        ....
>
```

Working demo - `app.component.ts` has the relevant code.
Changing the filters should log all the filters to the console.
https://embed.plnkr.co/Ymz4CSFVmXirnxCFlAeE/